# Razor template not working. Something is wrong in _ViewStart.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

_ViewStart.cshtml section is not working at all. Below is the output

```
<input type="text" value="{ class = big-field, tabindex = 1 }" name="Chris" id="Chris">
```

---

***//Edit.aspx***

```
@model myproject.Web.Models.ViewModel.User.EditViewModel

@{
    View.Title = "Edit Profile";
    Func<myproject.Web.Models.ViewModel.User.EditViewModel, HelperResult> lst = ViewContext.Controller.ViewData["CreateEditViewModelTemplate"] as Func<myproject.Web.Models.ViewModel.User.EditViewModel, HelperResult>;    
}

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again.")
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)
     @lst(Model)


    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit"  class="right-button" value="Back to Profile List"   style="margin: 5px 0 5px 0" , tabindex="7"/>
        <input type="submit"  class="right-button" value="Update Profile" name="confirmButton"  , tabindex="6"/>
    </fieldset>
}




using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myproject.Web.Core.Helpers
{
    public abstract class ViewStartPageWithHelpers : ViewStartPage
    {
        public static void WriteLiteralTo(TextWriter writer, object content)
        {
            writer.Write(content);
        }
        public static void WriteTo(TextWriter writer, object content)
        {
            writer.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(content));
        }
    }

}
```

***//_ViewStart.cshtml***

```
@using myproject.Web.Models.ViewModel.User;
@using myproject.Web.Core.Helpers;

@{
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@inherits ViewStartPageWithHelpers
@{
    Func<CreateViewModel, HelperResult> h =
     @<fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>
        <div>
            @{<table class="form-spacing">                      
                <tr>
                    <td class="cell-one">* @Html.Label(item.FirstName) :</td>
                    <td class="cell-two">@Html.TextBox(item.FirstName, new { @class = "big-field", tabindex = "1" })</td>
                    <td class="cell-three" >@Html.ValidationMessage(item.FirstName)</td>            
                </tr>
            </table>};
         </div>
    </fieldset>;

    ViewContext.Controller.ViewData["CreateEditViewModelTemplate"]=h;
}
```

Comment: What issue specifically are you seeing? An exception (what's the stack)? Things are just not executing?

Comment: See the output thats what I am getting instead of whole html chunk meaning whole FieldSet. Help please

Comment: I'm confused...you say the _viewstart is not working, but in your output you clearly have output from the _viewstart helper...I think we need a bit more explanation on your desired result and the exact issue you are seeing with _viewstart.

Comment: it looks like Ryan answered your question. Can you accept his answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the wierd value you have in your input element it's because you're using the wrong Html.TextBox overload on accident.  Try

`Html.TextBox(item.FirstName, item.FirstName, new {@class = "big-field", tabindex = "1" })`

Or use strong-types in the overload you choose.

Comment: Yes you got it right. That is the problem. But Html.Label and Html.ValidationMessage not working. Can you fix that?

Comment: You should be able to use Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName) which will automatically wireup a label for your textbox.  You should only need a Html.ValidationMessage() at the top of your page and any validation errors should be returned from your controller (or you model if your using DataAnnotations).